# Is there any benefit for base64 over resources in Android?

Tags: android, image, base64

I've got 2 .plst files, one of 5.2MB, the other bit smaller to embed into my Android App.

App is port from iOS, so in files I have images for iPad retina, and iPhone retina. Files are with multiple Base64 images.

Reading a bit, I've came to conclusion that having images that are static on the device in Base64 file is no advantage at all.

Can anyone help and explain why would I keep images in .xml file, instead saving them as .png, name them and add to drawables? is there any benefit?

I won't be sending this images anywhere, upload them, use the network.. they will reside on device all the time.

Tnx.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should use plain old png as is recommended on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using standard resources (or assets/ depending on your needs) is "natural" way of doing that on Android. Using base64 as you described is pointless here and makes things worse as you need to to decode these assets prior use which means using time and resources. Stick to provided platform mechanisms...

Comment: I guess I should mark your answer as "accepted", but will leave for a while, maybe someone has different opinion. Mine is similar to yours, that why I do not understand why I got resources in huge XML...

Comment: @balyto: Base64 as any ASCII "container" is ineffective because it usually sticks to 7 bit characters, which means your output will at least be 1/7th bigger than original file (it will be bigger than this, due to some additional chars used (i.e. LFs) or some sort of "escaping" (like "=...."). So if you definitely know you need Base64 or QP then you most likely do not need to use it.